# Multitasking app switcher screenshot is upside-down for landscape iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am developing a universal iOS application that is restricted to landscape-only mode on iPhones, which makes use of the `UIActivityViewController`. After clicking on any of the options within the activity view (Message, Mail, etc.), when exiting the app by pressing the home button once, the screenshot that appears in the app switcher is stretched and rotated upside-down, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRYKD.png). This problem also appears with Game Center leaderboards.

Note that this does not occur when leaving the app by double tapping the home button - in that case the app switcher has a perfectly normal landscape screenshot. The problem also is not present on iPads.

I have read posts online involving (and also experienced for myself) the same problem when banner ads from certain frameworks are present within a view, however those solutions generally involved simply removing the ad from superview upon `UIApplicationWillResignActive` and re-adding it upon `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive`.

Obviously I'd prefer an actual solution, but if this is caused by a bug on Apple's end then I guess a similar workaround will do. Also I'm using Objective-C, not Swift.

Answer (score 0):

My developers have also hit the same issue. I did suggest to them that perhaps placing a static predefined preview screen in the task switcher might help as per the instructions at http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-control-the-preview-screenshot-in-the-ios-multitasking-switcher/

Sadly, they say they attempted this but it still resulted in an upside down stretched image. Might be worth testing at your end though. I guess you could just use a solid black image for the preview and thus the user wouldn't notice it was upside down and stretched. Not sure how elegant that is though or whether Apple would like it.

I also suggested trying to set the initial landscape rotation to the opposite way, but they say that didn't help.